Linx cross-compilation for Arm Architecture
I am trying to compile latest linux kernel on my windows machine for arm architecture. I am unable to find the correct version of make. It requires GNU Make >= 3.82, The one I have is 3.81. Please let me know where I can I find the latest version for make for windows. Also I'm fairly new to this and do not know the list of tools that might be required and their versions(I would not like to use any virtual machines)

I'm fairly new not like to use any virtual machines are you sure? for make for windows There is no "GNU make for windows". There is GNU make (point). GNU make source code can be found upstream https://www.gnu.org/software/make/ . But you are not on a POSIX system, so you wont' be able to compile it most probably. It's up to you how to solve that issue. Even Cygwin has make 4.4 https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/make.html . Make==3.81 is 15 years (!) old

@KamilCuk, there is: https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm. (Yet, we are not talking about how it's relevant to the date.)
